# import _tkinter fails in Heroku environment

Tags: python, tkinter, heroku

I tried deploying my flask application in Heroku.
I used tkinter for GUI and I have included all the packages in the requirement.txt file.
In Local it is working fine, but after deployed to Heroku it shows the following error,

```
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697261+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697261+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697261+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697262+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 883, in exec_module
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 1, in 
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697265+00:00 app[web.1]: from tkinter import mainloop
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697265+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in 
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697265+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697265+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.697323+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:15 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.723967+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.723979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724183+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724185+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 551, in manage_workers
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724330+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724332+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 623, in spawn_workers
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724470+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724554+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724556+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724673+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724717+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: 
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724719+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724720+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724720+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724721+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724730+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in 
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724794+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724796+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724864+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724871+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724955+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.724957+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725023+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725025+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725106+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725107+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725205+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725213+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725308+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725398+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725399+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725519+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.725552+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: 
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.874173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.942483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2022-07-20T05:59:15.946546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2022-07-20T05:59:35.816070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.907700+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.908020+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:24560 (4)
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.908054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.911669+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919301+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919302+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919315+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919316+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919316+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919317+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919317+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919318+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919318+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919318+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919319+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919320+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919320+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 883, in exec_module
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 1, in 
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919322+00:00 app[web.1]: from tkinter import mainloop
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in 
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919323+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919323+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.919388+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.948876+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2022-07-20T05:59:36.948903+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-20 05:59:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
    2022-07-20T05:59:37.089440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
    2022-07-20T05:59:37.179362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2022-07-20T05:59:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2022-07-20T06:00:02.517793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=handy-digits.herokuapp.com request_id=d9913db6-f121-4011-b516-311b972e4524 fwd="101.127.226.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-07-20T06:00:03.070675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=handy-digits.herokuapp.com request_id=f28ca7b5-d147-4589-bbea-3b09827c5f27 fwd="101.127.226.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-07-20T06:02:42.235940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=handy-digits.herokuapp.com request_id=392e5e15-49d0-4895-a313-7a5e8ea5187b fwd="101.127.226.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-07-20T06:02:42.824608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=handy-digits.herokuapp.com request_id=5ffe155b-914b-4294-b348-7c73d2f7d1b7 fwd="101.127.226.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

reuirement.txt file

```
    absl-py==1.2.0
    astunparse==1.6.3
    cachetools==5.2.0
    certifi==2022.6.15
    charset-normalizer==2.1.0
    click==8.1.3
    colorama==0.4.5
    cv==1.0.0
    Flask==2.1.3
    flatbuffers==1.12
    gast==0.4.0
    google-auth==2.9.1
    google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
    google-pasta==0.2.0
    grpcio==1.47.0
    gunicorn==20.1.0
    h5py==3.7.0
    idna==3.3
    itsdangerous==2.1.2
    Jinja2==3.1.2
    keras==2.9.0
    Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
    libclang==14.0.1
    Markdown==3.4.1
    MarkupSafe==2.1.1
    numpy==1.23.1
    oauthlib==3.2.0
    opencv-python==4.6.0.66
    opt-einsum==3.3.0
    packaging==21.3
    Pillow==9.2.0
    protobuf==3.19.4
    pyasn1==0.4.8
    pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    pyparsing==3.0.9
    pywin32==304
    requests==2.28.1
    requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
    rsa==4.8
    six==1.16.0
    tensorboard==2.9.1
    tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
    tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
    tensorflow==2.9.1
    tensorflow-estimator==2.9.0
    tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.26.0
    termcolor==1.1.0
    tk==0.1.0
    typing_extensions==4.3.0
    urllib3==1.26.10
    Werkzeug==2.1.2
    wrapt==1.14.1
```

Couldn't figure out the reason for this issue in Heroku environment even the packages are included. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run flask app directly without gunicorn. Gunicorn runs multiple instances of your flask app and can cause your project to fail if you didn't account for asynchronous code/simultaneous access to same files. Your project should work without gunicorn.
2. you provided a log of the runtime error, provide the build log if all packages were correctly installed.
3. Installing Tkinter makes no sense on Heroku since it is running headless. There is no graphical user interface for your to interact with. You can run a webserver and access it in browser however Tkinter does not provide a webserver.
4. I can see from your requirements.txt that

- a few packages will not be installed. Heroku uses a Linux system you are installing pywin32.
- You don't install tk with https://pypi.org/project/tk/. If you visit the source code you see it no longer exists. The project isn't maintained and was uploaded and forgotten sometime. Install tkinter with the Apt package python-tk or python3-tk. Besides your Python buidpack you need the Apt buildpack https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
- tensorflow is too big of a package and will fail on Heroku. The maximum slug size is 500MB https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#slug-size

All in all I don't think Heroku is achieving your goal. There are way too many issues and your project may be just incompatible with Heroku.